# Finding duplicates and fixing them

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was wondering if there was a way to find duplicate values in Google sheets regardless of formatting errors and also fix them.

For example, list one is literally the same as list two. But in sheets the duplicates aint picked up.

```
List One:
Alcatel
Apple
Benq-Siemens
Blackberry
Google
HTC
Huawei
LG
Manufacturer
Motorola
Nokia
One Plus
Samsung
Sony-Ericcson

List Two:
Manufacturer
Alcatel
apple
benqsiemens
Blackberry
Google
hTC
Huawei
lg
Manufacturer
Motorola
Nokia
One Plus
Samsung
Sonyericcson
```

Please note in the List Two the only ones with errors as in formatting errors are `apple`,`benqsiemens`,`hTC`,`lg`,`Sonyericsson`.

How do I do it so that the two list have all duplicates selected despite any formatting errors and also fix them?

Thanks

Comment: Is your list one always have the correct format? And regarding your concern to fix the format, does it mean you want to modify your list two format? Or you just want to get the list of duplicates in list one and list two with the fixed format and no need to modify list two items. I would appreciate it if you could provide your expected output

Comment: @RonM Hi so yes List One is always the correct format. sometimes I can manually see the same word in List Two but because of formatting issues the Google sheets doesnt pick it up. ONly i do manually. The idea is to compare the two lists and keep duplicates and at the same time make sure LIst Two is same format as List One

Comment: I believe it is impossible to update your list two and fix it's format using sheets formula. How about first we fix the format of the duplicates in list two using apps script. Would it be  OK from your side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF(REGEXMATCH(PROPER(C2:C),REGEXEXTRACT(PROPER(B2:B),"\w+")),B2:B,"MANUAL FIX")))
```

[image]

`MANUAL FIX` you have when formula can not fix it.
You have to first fix `C` and then formula will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check out example Example 4. Compare two Google Sheets for differences to compare the two sheets https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/04/30/google-sheets-compare-two-sheets-columns/

Comment: Is there like a formula for it? I was thinking of using `PROPER` but that only capitalises first letters

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code on how to fix the format of your list two based on list one:

```
function fixDuplicates() {
  var listOne = 'Sheet2!A2:A';
  var listTwo = 'Sheet2!B2:B';

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var listOneVal = sheet.getRange(listOne).getDisplayValues().flat().filter(String);
  var listTwoRange = sheet.getRange(listTwo);
  var listTwoVal= listTwoRange.getDisplayValues().flat().filter(String);
  //clone list two value
  var tmpListTwo = [...listTwoVal];

  
  //Update Temp List Two Values,remove spaces, special characters and set to uppercase 
  tmpListTwo.forEach((val,index) => {
    tmpListTwo[index] = val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,"").toUpperCase();
  });

  //Find list one value in temp list two
  listOneVal.forEach(val =>{
    //Remove spaces, special characters and set to uppercase
    var tmp = val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,"").toUpperCase();

    var index = tmpListTwo.indexOf(tmp);
    if(index != -1){
      Logger.log("Finding: "+listTwoVal[index]);
      var textFinder = listTwoRange.createTextFinder(listTwoVal[index]);
      var firstOccurrence = textFinder.findNext();
      if(firstOccurrence!=null){
        //duplicate found, fix the duplicate format. set cell value based on list one value
        firstOccurrence.setValue(val);
        Logger.log("Value set to: "+val);
      }
    }

  });

}
```

### What it does?

1. Define your list one and two range in A1Notation (Including the sheet name)
2. Get the values of your list one and two, change 2-d array to 1-d array using array.flat() and remove empty-cell values using array.filter()
3. Clone your list two array. Format your temporary list two array by removing all special characters, spaces and set it to upper case.
4. Loop all your list one value, transform your current list one value by also removing special characters, spaces and set to upper case. Get the index of list one value in your temporary list two array.
5. Once we determined the duplicates in list two, we will use [Range.createTextFinder(findText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext) to search for the duplicate's range. Then set its value using [Range.setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) using your list one value.

### Output:

[image]

- See your original list two value in column F
- After running the code, it was transformed to the one in column B
- See Cell C1, on how to get the duplicates in column B using the formula: `=Filter(B2:B,MATCH(A2:A,B2:B,0))`